# Where to set nbextensions directory for IPython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm starting ipython notebook with something like

```
ipython notebook --ipython-dir='C:\IProfile'
```

Now I wanted to install an extension ("Notifications" from https://github.com/sjpfenninger/ipython-extensions).

So I copy the file "notify.js" and modify my "custom.js" accordingly to load it. Now it seems it only works if I copy the "notify.js" file to the default `C:\User\Name\.ipython\nbextensions`, but not if I copy the file to `C:\IProfile\nbextensions` as I expected.

How can I make IPython find the extension in `C:\IProfile\nbextensions`?